# Proper way to intersect two types using flow

Tags: types, flowtype

I recently learned about how to intersect types in flow. I'm curious what the difference is 
between the following two approaches for intersecting two object types:

Say that I have the following two types to intersect.

```
type A = {
   foo: string
}

type B = {
   bar: boolean
}
```

And I want to intersect them to create a type C that looks like this

```
type C = {
  foo: string,
  bar: boolean
}
```

Approach 1:

```
type C = A & B
```

Approach 2:

```
type C = {...A, ...B}
```

Are these approaches equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are not equivalent.

At first, I can't think of a case when `&` is useful (because it's broken). I'd suggest to use spread always.

The [basic difference](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoK6BmB7LAuKAzsAE4CWAdgOYoC+KKokUAQgsmugEYCGx+nOADa16jaAGEAjGzgAyFqPASATGyQA6TTAA0UTeuZ0UgiMCgBjSfilqo2PFADkjqDQDc9E2fPLrqxEh2OPjOrm5AA): spread makes all the properties optional if your type is non-exact. You [can](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoK6BmB7LAuKAzsAE4CWAdgOYoC+KKokUAQgsmugEYCGx+nOADa16jaAGEAjGzgAyFqPASATGyQA6TQBIAogA9uAY2AAeGAD4ANFE3rdB4yebm6KQRGBRDk-FLVRsPCgAcmCoGgBuendPQ2VfVUQkAJx8UPCIoA) fix it with `$Exact` utility.

The right way to do things is to declare all your types as exact. Flow has a configuration option for that and it [will become a default behavior](https://medium.com/flow-type/on-the-roadmap-exact-objects-by-default-16b72933c5cf) in the future. But `&` [does not work](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAfAUFTAzA9jgXFAM7ABOAlgHYDmaKAvmmqJFAEILLqZQBGAhqUK88AGzqNm4aAGEAjJzgAydkxayATJyQA6PTAA0UPTraTREYFADGcwvO1RcBKAHJXRgUKhkArtHoAbiYLK2sNey1EJCc8QncoIKA) with exact types while spread does.

The result of an intersection is [often](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/7523) [a](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6680) [broken](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/8050) type.

Comment: Thanks for the detail, and the examples in the flow repl!

Comment: > The basic difference: spread makes all the properties optional if your type is non-exact. You can fix it with $Exact utility.

This isn't true as of 0.106. Flow will error if it cannot soundly infer a precise type instead of inferring optional/mixed properties. See https://medium.com/flow-type/coming-soon-changes-to-object-spreads-73204aef84e1

Comment: Thanks, that’s useful addition!